# Why isn't this JOptionPane showing up?

Tags: java, swing, function, user-interface, methods

I'm trying to show a JOptionPane input dialog and then have the view come up after but I am not sure why it is not appearing, the view pops up but not the input dialog, I try commenting out the view part and nothing happens

Here is my controller where the JOptionPane input dialog is

```
package model;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;




public class Controller {
    private View myView;
    private NQueensModel myModel;
    private static int int1, possibilities;
    private static String intString;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        intString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many rows/cols?");
        int1 = Integer.parseInt(intString);
    }

    public Controller()
    {
        myView = new View(this);

    }
    public void solve()
    {

        myView.doViewGrid();
        myModel = new NQueensModel(int1);
        myModel.solvePuzzle();
        possibilities = myModel.getPossibilities();
        myView.addButtons();
        myView.setPossibilitiesLabel(possibilities);
        myView.revalidate();
        myView.repaint();




    }

    public boolean[][] getMyBoard()
    {
        return myModel.getBoard();
    }



}
```

here is the main class where the controller is first called

```
package model;

public class queensBasics
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Controller myController = new Controller();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
intString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many rows/cols?");
```

is located in the `main` method of the `Controller` class rather that in `queensBasics` which is the application's entry point. Simply move this statement to the latter

```
public class QueenBasics {
  public static void main() {
     String intString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many rows/cols?");
     // process/pass in intString to Controller 
     ...
  }
}
```